# Gershgorin's Theorem for a matrix X'X when X'X cannot be computed

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there any way to estimate or approximate the largest eigenvalue of X'X using X alone? I know that this can be done by approximating the singular values of X, but I'm looking for another approach. Based on Gershgorin's theorem, we know that the largest eigenvalue is less than the maximum row/column sum of X'X.

EDIT: this seems promising but I'm not sure how to use it http://user.it.uu.se/~maya/Courses/NLA/Hands_on/Matrix_Decomp_2011/LiqunQi_SVD.pdf

EDIT2: another potentially useful paper is the following:
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10958-009-9355-9

Comment: $X'$ is the transpose?

Comment: yes, sorry for the ambiguity